# rutas relativas Spring Boot con server.contextPath

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

amigos, como puedo trabajr con rutas relativas en spring boot con server.contextPath = /prueba, es para encontrar un archivo de jasperReport
[image: estructura del proyecto]

Comment: El `server.contextPath` establece la ruta contexto para acceso a la aplicación, desde un navegador. Creo que lo que tú haces es intentar cargar una plantilla para generar un informe internamente, por lo que esa propiedad es irrelevante.

Answer (score 0):

Estas son las 3 formas de hacer las rutas relativas con spring boot, a mi personalmente me funcionó la última:

```
server.context-path=/miapp

server.servlet-path=/miapp

server.servlet.contextPath=/miapp
```

Cualquier de ellas, debes incluirlas en el application.properties